# Rails 4: has_many :through errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is my join model:

```
class CompanyUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user
end
```

My `User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  ROLES = %w[admin requestor requestor_limited shipping_vendor].freeze

  attr_accessor :temp_password

  has_many :companies_users

  ...

end
```

If I run this in the console:

```
u = User.first
u.companies
```

This is the error I am getting:

`NameError: uninitialized constant User::CompaniesUser`

Comment: It should be `has_many company_users` and also you should be having `has_many :users,:through => company_users` in your `User` model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

has_many through relationships should be like this:

**In app/models/company.rb file**,

```
  has_many :company_users
  has_many :users, :through => :company_users
```

**In app/models/user.rb file**,

```
  has_many :company_users
  has_many :companies, :through => :company_users
```

**In app/models/company_user.rb file**,

```
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user
```

If you want to delete the dependent records in company_users table when deleting companies/users,

Add, `, :dependent => :destroy` at the end of has_many relations in Company and User model.

Hope this helps you..

Thanks.!!

Comment: I named the table `companies_users`, should it be named `company_users`?

Answer (score 3):

it must be

```
has_many :company_users
```

> "CompanyUser".tableize  => "company_users"

Answer (score 1):

The model shall be either:

```
class CompaniesUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Or `has_many` declaration sheel be defined explicitly as:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :company_users
end
```